# AWS .NET SDK S3 Multipart Upload with user defined Metadata

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm implementing a simple C# client that needs to upload files big and small to S3. I need to set user defined metadata for a multipart S3 upload. For a simple S3 PutObject, I simply set the metadata on the request as follow:

```
putObjectRequest.Metadata.Add("my-key", "my-value")
```

I've worked through the documentation, [Using the AWS .NET SDK for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingLLmpuDotNet.html), and I'm at a bit of a loss on how to set the metadata for a multipart upload.

How do I set the user defined metadata for a multipart upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 multipart uploads require the user metadata to be supplied when you initiate the multipart upload (you can't supply it any later in the process).

The [`Amazon.S3.Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3S3InitiateMultipartUploadInitiateMultipartUploadRequest.html) has a `Metadata` property that is an instance of [`Amazon.S3.Model.MetadataCollection`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3MetadataCollection.html), which you'd need to supply when constructing the `InitiateMultipartUploadRequest`.

The following code snippet illustrates setting values on the Metadata property:

```
// Create the S3 Initiate Multipart Upload Request
var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = "my-bucket-name",
    Key = "my-file-name"
};

// Populate the S3 Request Metadata
initiateRequest.Metadata.Add("my-key", "my-value");
```